# Listener for Azure function was unable to start error while running Azure function app locally. How to solve this?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-storage-emulator

I have one Azure function app. I am trying to run that locally but getting the below error. I have the storage emulator up and running.
[Storage emulator status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ypPo.png)

[Storage emulator status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsMpI.png)

I am not sure why it is complaining about 10000 port because my storage emulator is running on 12000,12001, 12002 respectively for blob, queue, table.

Local host file is like below,

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
}
}
```

Getting the below error at runtime. Can you pls guide me how the issue can be solved to run the function app locally?

The listener for function 'ABCFunction' was unable to start. Azure.Core: Retry failed after 6 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry. (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (127.0.0.1:10000)) (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (127.0.0.1:10000)) (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (127.0.0.1:10000)) (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (127.0.0.1:10000)) (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (127.0.0.1:10000)) (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (127.0.0.1:10000)). Azure.Core: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (127.0.0.1:10000). System.Net.Http: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: just run the emulator with Admin priviledges, that should work

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio , I start the emulator with Admin privileges but still that is not working. My 10000 port is busy to do something so I changed the port of emulator from AzureStorageEmulator.exe.config file and started with admin mood. it started successfully. I am not sure why it is trying to find the listener on port 10000 if I run the function app from Visual Studio. Can you guide me?

Comment: I have this same issue. I tried running from the CMD as administrator, but all the Azure stuff I installed isn't accessible -- I get 'func' isn't an internal or external command.

Comment: @BenW for that you need to install azure function core tool globally

Comment: azure functions use Azure Storage Emulator. It has no relationship with the port your azure function is running. I do recommend you reinstall the Azure Storage Emulator

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, your storage emulator is running on port 12000, 12001, 12002. You can try the following.

**Check if endpoint is running**

`In CMD`

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator>AzureStorageEmulator.exe status
```

**Check storage emulator sql database is created and can start**

```
AzureStorageEmulator.exe init
```

**Check if have port conflict issue**

```
AzureStorageEmulator.exe start
```

Change to other ports if needed

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe.config
```

Then

```
AzureStorageEmulator.exe start
```

You can also explicitly specify the `AzureWebJobsStorage` to the url you specified

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:12000/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:12001/devstoreaccount1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue.

[image]

I can fix this by using below steps:

Make sure you run your **Storage Emulator** with **Admin** privileges. Which was already mentioned by @ [Thiago Custodio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1384539/thiago-custodio).

Killing the **Function process** & **host process** in the task manager

[image]

Now I can able to run the azure function without issue:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i had this issue and for some reason the emulator wasnt even installed, i installed it from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator and now works fine, not sure why wasnt installed